# How-to kill my app without killing the service it sarted (debugging)

Tags: android

My android application starts a service when runned for the first time. That service handles network connection.

If the device is out of free space, my application can be killed, but the service will remain alive (except on certain extreme case, I know.). When the app will be restarted, it will need to restore it state according to the service state (no problem for that).

Here's my question: How can I kill my application, but not the associated service ? That's only for debugging purpose, I would like to test if the state is correctly restored.

When I try to kill the app with adb, ddms or advanced task killer, the service is killed too.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Code: I start my service like that:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);
mStartServiceResult = startService(intent);
mIsBound = bindService(intent, mConnection, 0);
```

and use startForeground / setForeground to prevent my service to be killed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the device is out of free space, my application can be killed, but the service will remain alive (except on certain extreme case, I know.).

No. Some or all of your activities might be destroyed, which would leave the service running. Or your process may be terminated, in which case your service will also shut down.

> How can I kill my application, but not the associated service ?

That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: However, if you want to test this case you may try having the activity call finish() on a timer after say 2 minutes. Assuming that doesn't stop your service, it may help with testing the restore case. Though it won't be exactly the same thing.

Comment: I've experienced some weird case: my main activity was killed by android (ie, onDestroy()) was not called, but the service was still alive. Do you tell me such a case it not possible ?

Comment: @Torp: I'll try that, finishing the app. without closing the server. Thanks :)

Comment: @Sébastien: They all run in one process normally, unless you messed something up in your manifest. The only time `onDestroy()` is not called is if you crash or if your process is terminated.